# Is the surface temperature of the sun constant?

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun, stellar-physics

I was just wondering that during the suns mains sequence would it maintain a constant temperature at the surface and only cool once the hydrogen in its core runs out, or is it always slowly decreasing?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to average stuff like sun spots and solar cycles and such?

Comment: Yes, I know that there will be variations across the sun, but as an average is it cooling down, or does it maintain  a roughly constant power output during its main sequence?

Comment: In other words, is the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) constant? It is not, but almost

Comment: [This plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_evolution_(English).svg) looks helpful.